# LineBreak not working in Binding of GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, sql-server-2008, line-breaks

In an ASP.NET application, I have multiline string values as listed below.

**Code:**

```
string remarks="Line 1 \n";
remarks+=remarks+"\n Line 2 \n";

Console.Writeln(remarks);
```

**Output:**

```
Line 1

Line 2
```

Now I want the same output of the string values, when I insert them into a table on a SQL Server, retrieve them back an then present them in a GridView by bindings.

But after the retrieval from the DB, I'm getting the whole string in one line only like this (the line breaks are not working):

```
Line 1Line 2
```

I tried `Environement.NewLine` and `StringBuilder` but I always get the output from the server as one-liner.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you inserting it into the database? How are you retreiving it?

Comment: Using Ado.NET with Stored Procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace "\n" with "
" on row bound event

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[i].Text = e.Row.Cells[i].Text.Replace("\\n", "<br/>");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL will maintain inserted linebreaks.

Linebreaks won't show up on the likes of a DataGridView object by default.
Try:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
```